# Difference of android apk export type to be used in android device

Tags: android, apk

I would like to know what is the difference between using the 
"Right click project -> Export -> Export Android Application"

[image: Export Android Application]

and "Right click project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package" as shown in the image below

[image]

May I know if they are actually doing the same thing?

Comment: i just checked it out, i think they are the same thing

Comment: JRowan, thank you for your reply. And I also think that they are the same too, but it is just that I am not very sure.

Comment: yeah they seem really simalar, if it helps any if you are exporting to put into googleplay ive always used the second way, i never used the first way and it works out fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are the same thing, i.e both of them EXPORT SIGNED APPLICATION to be distributed.

1. "`Right click project -> Export -> Export Android Application`" exports Signed Application
2. "`Right click project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package`" also exports Signed Application

Hope this helps!